# AngularJS app title rendering as {{metaTitle}} when link is pasted in Skype

Tags: angularjs, skype

I am building an AngularJS based web app. I am populating the title tag dyanmically, so that it changes for every page. When I host the app online & share the link to it over Skype with my friends (via Skype instant messaging), instead of rendering the parsed value of `metaTitle`, Skype renders it as {{metaTitle}}. So my friends are getting to see the curly braces with the `metaTitle` as text inside of it.

What can be done to render the parsed value of `metaTitle` in Skype and other native applications that actually show you a preview of the link that has been pasted, as a part of the chat messages?

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
      <title>{{metaTitle}}</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
      Custom content
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe try with `<title ng-bind="metaTitle"></title>` ?  although I have a feeling it might just copy and paste an empty title.

Comment: What is {{metaTitle}}? i mean from where it is coming?

Comment: Is it defined in controller then see it is not inside your controller.

Comment: I am populating the value of {{metaTitle}} from my Controller. I have also tried `ng-bind` but that still shows the same result.

Comment: So see it is not inside your controller, it is above your controller.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Do you mean, I have to put it outside of my controller or inside of it?

Comment: Yes @Devner i know but it's not possible to bind your title dynamically how you are doing.

Comment: For sure, this will be helpful for you.. https://coderwall.com/p/vcfo4q/angularjs-change-title-based-on-route

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya I will try that too.

Comment: Sure, @Devner it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the real, dynamic title, you'll need to render the page at server-side for these robots (or serve a static cache of the page), because they don't execute the JavaScript that allows populating the title.

Otherwise, you can use

```
<title ng-bind="metaTitle">Static title for Skype</title>
```

Comment: Bu this will render the same, static message for every page. Correct? So for example, say I use the static message as "Welcome" & if I paste the link to the homepage, then my friends may see "Welcome". If I paste the link to the Contact page, then they will still see "Welcome" as the message instead of showing something like "Contact". Can this be fixed?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, as I said in my answer, by generating the title at server-side. Instead of serving a static index.html page, you would serve a dynamically-generated page, as we all did before JS single-page frameworks like Angular became popular.

Comment: Thanks, I got that. But I can't change the framework now, nor I can dump AngularJS for another framework. So is it still possible to achieve this now, with the current structure & framework at hand?

Comment: You could use a general title for all pages when running the app on "static mode".

Comment: I didn't say you had to dump Angular. I said that you could, *in addition* to using Angular, generate some pages, or some parts of the pages, at server-side, so that robots without JavaScript render things that don't look too ugly. Or that you could generate a static cache of your web application and serve pages from that static cache for robots. There are online services doing that for you, if you want.

Comment: Could you please share any good resources that you may have personally found to be interesting in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Skype doesn't execute/interpret the JavaScript (in this case AngularJS) within the page. All Skype knows is the static HTML content.

You might want to look into server-side rendering or having a static landing page for your app.

Edit: As per @JB Nizet answer, you can also use the following syntax.

```
<title ng-bind="metaTitle">Static title for Skype</title>
```

Comment: I think I have tried it already, but let me give it a shot again.

Answer (score -1):

Since you mention that you are populating metaTitle from your controller, you need to move your controller declaration to html tag:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<head>
      <title>{{metaTitle}}</title>
</head>
<body>
      Custom content
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're right about declaring the controller on the parent node. However, the problem OP is facing is to do with the robot (Skype) not executing the JavaScript in the page.

Comment: I do it this way: `$scope.$parent.metaTitle="Home";`. So moving the ng-controller to the html does not solve my issue.

Comment: I see sense in what @JB Nizet is trying to say, so maybe if you can add something on those lines, I can try that & maybe that will help me.

Comment: You have to think that no matter what JavaScript code you write (Vanilla, Angular or any other framework), it won't be executed by the Skype renderer.